# Stuck with finding the equation for the period of oscillation of a mass under a gaussian potential

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, oscillators

I'm trying to find an equation for the period of oscillation of a mass under the following potential:

$U(x) = - U_0 \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})$

I'm trying by doing the following:

$F = -\frac{dU}{dx} = \frac{-d(-U_0 \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}))}{du} = \frac{2U_0\cdot \exp(-x²/\sigma²)x}{\sigma^2}$

$ m\cdot a= \frac{2U_0\cdot \exp(-x²/\sigma²)x}{\sigma^2} \rightarrow a = \frac{2U_0\cdot \exp(-x²/\sigma²)x}{\sigma^2 m} $

and then
$a = -\omega²x $ and proceding to find the period $T$ where $\omega^2$ is $\frac{2U_0\cdot \exp(-x²/\sigma²)}{\sigma^2 m}$ but that seems not logic since I still have -x² in the exponent...

Comment: The relationship $a=\omega^2 x$ assumes the oscillation follows simple harmonic motion, this isn't always true, you have to replace it with the more general $a=\ddot{x}$ and then solve the associated differential equation.

Comment: And how will I find the period if I don't know the $\omega$?

Comment: It's not an easy task for a general differential equation, consider how the full ODE for the simple pendulum results in elliptic integrals for the expression of the period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all we assume $U_0>0$. Then we get a Gaussian potential well.

We deal here with a periodical motion of particle in Gaussian potential well. The period of such a motion can be computed from energy conservation of this motion in the potential well:

$$\frac{2}{m}(E-U(x))=v^2 =\left(\frac{dx}{dt}\right)^2$$

where $E$ is the total energy of the particle, $m$ its mass and $v$ its velocity. The particle is in a bound state, therefore its total energy $E<0$.

The time from one turning point --- which we'll call $x_m$  --- to the opposite turning point is half of the revolution time (also called period).

We can obtain this time interval $T/2$ by taking the root of the reciprocal of the rhs of the precedent equation followed by an integration from one turning point to the opposite one (as the potential well is an even function we have 2 symmetrical turning points $x_m$ and $-x_m$):

$$ \frac{T}{2} =\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\int_{-x_m}^{x_m} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{E-U(x)}}$$

The integral can be further simplified since the integrand is an even function --- on top it we multiply both side by a factor of 2:

$$T = 4 \sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\int_0^{x_m} \frac{dx}{\sqrt{E-U(x)}}$$

We are almost done, the last detail needed for the computation of the period $T$ is the computation of the coordinate of the turning point. We get it easily from energy conservation and the knowledge that the kinetic energy at the turning points is zero:

$$ E = 0 - U_0 exp(-\frac{x_m^2}{2\sigma^2}) $$

which yields if solved for $x_m$:

$$x_m = \sigma \sqrt{-2 \ln\left( \frac{-E}{U_0}\right)}$$

In this way we obtain the final expression for the revolution time:

$$T = 4\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\int_0^{\sigma\sqrt{-2\ln\left( \frac{-E}{U_0}\right)}}\frac{dx}{  \sqrt{E+U_0 \exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2}) } }$$

The integral very probably represents a non-elementary function, so it can only be solved numerically. But what it important here is the fact the revolution time $T$ will be function of the energy. This mean the revolution time will depend on the amplitude of the oscillations. Actually this is not so surprising, the only potential which will lead to a completely harmonic motion where $T$ is a constant is the quadratical potential well. So it is tempting to try an approximation:

$$U(x) \approx -U_0 + U_0 \frac{X^2}{2}$$

where we haved introduced the variable $X =\frac{x}{\sigma}$. If we plug this into the integral we get:

$$T = 4\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\int_0^{x_m} \frac{dx}{  \sqrt{E+U_0 -U_0\frac{X^2}{2} } }$$

In order to avoid confusion we will introduce variable $e= -E >0$. We can more easily calculate with $e$. Then we get for the integral:

$$T = 4\sqrt{\frac{m}{2}}\int_0^{x_m} \frac{dx}{  \sqrt{(U_0-e) -U_0\frac{X^2}{2} } }  =  4\sqrt{\frac{m}{U_0}}\sigma \int_0^{X_m} \frac{dX}{  \sqrt{2\frac{U_0-e}{U_0} -X^2 } } =  4\sigma\sqrt{\frac{m}{U_0} } arcsin \frac{X}{\sqrt{2 \frac{U_0-e}{U_0} }}|^{X_m}_0 $$

The equation for the  turning point coordinate $X_m= \frac{x_m}{\sigma}$ normalized on $\sigma$ is the following in case of the quadratical approximation (remember $e=-E$):

$$E = -U_0 + U_0 \frac{X_m^2}{2} \quad \rightarrow \quad X^2_m = 2 \left(\frac{U_0-e}{U_0}\right)$$

Now if we plug this expression in the argument of the arcsin function we get:

$$T = 4\sigma\sqrt{\frac{m}{U_0} } arcsin 1 = 4\sigma\sqrt{\frac{m}{U_0} } \frac{\pi}{2} = 2\pi \sigma \sqrt{\frac{m}{U_0} }$$

which is the revolution time for a harmonic oscillator as expected. In particular we observe that the energy $E=-e$ is cancelled out. Therefore the revolution time is in this particular case independent of the amplitude.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have a restoring force which is a linear function of distance. the period will be a function of the amplitude.  If you are interested in just the small amplitude period, you might use the first term in a power series expansion of the force function.

Answer (score 1):

Unless $U_0$ is negative, there is no oscillation. It's a repulsive potential so any particle will run away to infinity. Did you perhaps expect $U_0$ to be negative? If so, then  for small oscillations you can approximate $e^{-x^2/2\sigma^2}\approx 1$.

Comment: Could you explain in more detail why unless $U_0$ is negative there is no oscillation?

Comment: @hcp because then it is a potential "hill" so to speak, an unstable equilibrium which means any deviation from that point causes the particle to move away from it.

Comment: another question related to that, what if I cannot use the limit for small oscillations?

Answer (score 1):

You get Frederic's answer in a more simple way by Taylor approximating first:

$$U \approx -U_0 (1 - \frac{x^2}{2 \sigma ^2})$$

$$F = -\frac{dU}{dx} = \frac{U_0}{\sigma^2}x$$

This is just Hooke's Law, with $k = \frac{U_0}{\sigma^2} $. Thus,

$$\omega = \sqrt{k/m} \\ \text{and}
\\ T = 2 \pi \sqrt{\frac{m}{k}} = 2 \pi \sigma \sqrt{\frac{m}{U_0}}$$